# $E(Y^2)$ and expected value?

Tags: probability, expectation

I have this theorem in my notes stating that $var(x)=E(x^2)-(MuX)^2$

the example with it is, given $MuX=5$ and $Var(x)=0.5$ then $E(x^2)=25.5$.

But what does $E(x^2)$ even mean?

I read elsewhere that it is the 2nd moment around the mean which is variance but the example clearly says variance is $0.5$.

Can it be converted to a simple expected value?

Answer (score 0):

Please use MathJax, you question is hard to read.

What you have in the first line is the $\mathit{definition}$ of variance, from with you can easily find $25.5 = 5^2 + 0.5$, $\mathbf{E}X^2$ is indeed the second moment, while $\mathbf{Var} X$ is the second $\textit{standard}$ moment (i.e. standardized around the mean.

EDIT: the original question was 'But what does E(x2) even mean?', which is very vague. What I can say is that variance of the random variable measures the discrepancy/diversion/dispersion from the mean,$ \ \mu$. The second moment, $\mathbf{E}X^2 \ \textit{arises} $ in the definition of variance, so computation of variance (normalized second moment) is impossible without the knowledge of the second moment.

Comment: So 5 is the mean, .5 is the average squared distance from the mean, but what is 25.5 in this case?

Comment: $25.5$ is the central moment, you don't see how it was obtained, do you?

Comment: I simply see that it is the sum of 25 and .5. But I don't understand its significance or meaning. What is it measuring? In layman's terms. I don't see the point of squaring the mean and then adding the average distance from the mean.

Comment: pls see the edit